# elastic search model init() raise key error

Tags: django, elasticsearch

According to the documentation I've created class with some of my model fields to perform search later. Also I've created conection with default params. But I can't call init() for `UserIndex`

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Text, Boolean, Date, Keyword
from elasticsearch_dsl.connections import connections

connections.create_connection(hosts=['localhost'], timeout=20)

class UserIndex(DocType):
    pk = Text()
    phone_number = Text()
    nickname = Text()
    name = Text()
    birth_date = Date()
    class Meta:
        index = 'user'
```

After `UserIndex.init()` command I'm getting an error:

```
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py", line 138, in init
    i.save(using=using)
  File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/index.py", line 289, in save
    current_settings = self.get_settings(using=using)[self._name]['settings']['index']
KeyError: '*'
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of elasticsearch-dsl are you using?  It looks like the latest version (6.3.0) is having issues ([This posted issue seems similar](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/1091)).

Rolling back to 6.2.1 resolved this error for me.